# Java - Change a variable's value in methods?

Tags: java, variables, boolean, private

I have a boolean variable, which is false. I would like to change that to true.

start.java

```
class start{
    static boolean click;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    second class1 = new second();
    System.out.println(class1.click);
  }
}
```

second.java

```
public class second{

     public boolean click;

     public void main2(){
     click = true;
     }

   }
```

Comment: in your case call main2 on class1 before sysout.

Comment: why do you need to downvote my question, huh? just because it's an easy question, you don't need to downvote, please man. come one.

Comment: I wasn't one of the downvoters, but I suppose people may not like your question because 1. you didn't show any effort in posing your question, and 2. They might think that this is stuff that any decent Java tutorial/class should cover, and isn't likely to be beneficial to future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to invoke the method that changes the `click` value, before printing it:

```
second class1 = new second();
class1.main2();
System.out.println(class1.click);
```

Comment: also, change `main2` to `setClick(boolean clicked){click = clicked;}`; usage: `class1.setClick(true);`